# DVD/CD not regognized on Thinkpad T61p after Windows 7 install

Tags: windows-7, dvd, thinkpad

I upgraded my hard drive in Lenovo T61P; decided to start fresh with Windows 7 Pro (64-bit). DVD/CD drive working until Windows 7 was installed.

Now the driver is not recognized. Device is `HL-DT-ST DVDRAM GSA-U10N ATA Device`. It appears on device manager but with the yellow tag; System tells me the driver is corrupted or not recognized. I Ran PC-Doctor and it reported all was OK.  Ran ParetoLogic Driver Cure which said the driver was fine.

I went from XP Professional (32-bit) to Windows 7 (64-bit) during this

Comment: Uninstall the HL-DT-ST DVDRAM GSA-U10N device in DM, reboot, see if it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following from the Microsoft site?:

http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;314060